# Observe UINavigationController navigationBar show/hide

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINaviationController` added through `storyboard` with selected options like `Hide Bars` `On Tap` etc. I was wondering what is the best solution to react to navigationBar and toolbar shows/hides. I tried overriding `UINavigationController` and methods like `setNavigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)`, but this doesn't get called when you tap to hide. I think it's probably possible to observe some variable, but I'm not sure which one and if it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
var ob:NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ob = self.navigationController?.observe(\.navigationBar.isHidden, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (nav, ob) in
        print("ok")
    })
}
```